# Invalid_grant:authentication failure when signing on to Salesforce Workbench

Tags: error, workbench

I'm unable to login to Salesforce Workbench using a custom Salesforce domain for Sandbox environment. I'm getting the error invalid_grant:authentication failed. However if i try to sign on to a Salesforce.com production domain with another user, I was successful

Comment: Hi Kon, welcome to SFSE. Would you please [edit] your question to include the specific sequence of steps you perform that results in this error? Please also include any germane configuration details of your sandbox org (SSO, login policies, etc).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I finally figured out the issue. I selected Production in the Environment drop down when I should have selected Sandbox instead

Comment: workbench.developerforce.com developerforce.com invalid grant  invalidgrant error invalid_grant .  login error login problem.   Kon (above) has THE SIMPLE ANSWER YOU ARE LOOKING FOR.   Thank you Kon.